# jQuery TE paragraph tag issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I have an issue with jQuery TE editor ([Download the files here](http://jqueryte.com/#download)) in that the paragraph tags are not wrapping where they should.

I get:

```
first sentence<p></p>second sentence<p></p>thirds sentence<p></p>
```

when it should be:

```
<p>first sentence</p><p>second sentence</p><p>thirds sentence</p>
```

For some reason it is placing the text outside of the tags. I've echoed the posted data below the form field to check.

[image: example of what I see and what code I've used]

Any ideas anyone? :-)